# Trying to perform a CRUD operation but the only request working is getting the whole data from my database .And when I tried i get this error message

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman

{
"status": "error",
"message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[Function (anonymous)]" (type function) at path "_id" for model "tours""
}

Comment: Please add code, to get answer..

Comment: Please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask in order to get benefitial feedback.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.